# Has my conjecture using Pell's Equation been discovered before

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, radicals, pell-type-equations

We have $$\sqrt{d} = \frac{x}{y} - \frac{1}{f_0\cdot y} - \frac{1}{f_0\cdot f_1\cdot y}- \ldots - \frac{1}{f_0\cdot f_1\cdot\ldots\cdot f_n\cdot y}-\ldots\,,$$
where 
$$f_0 = 2x\,,$$
$$f_{n+1} = (f_n)^2 - 2\text{ for }n=0,1,2,\ldots,$$
and $x$ and $y$ are nontrivial solutions to Pell's Equation $x^2 - d\cdot y^2 = 1$.

For example:

$$\sqrt{5} = 9/4 - 1/72 - 1/23184 - 1/2043763488 -\ldots\,.$$

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange. As you see in the edited answer you can use the usual LaTeX syntax here to make your math nicely formated.

Comment: Maybe there is a limit on the right hand side? LHS is irrational, RHS is rational as it stands

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is published somewhere, but in my opinion it has little to do with Pell equation.

From $x^2-d y^2=1$ you deduce $d=\left(\frac xy\right)^2-\frac1{y^2}=\left(\frac xy\right)^2\left(1-\frac1{x^2}\right)$, hence $\sqrt d = \frac xy \sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}}$. Your identity can be written as
$$
\sqrt{d} = \frac xy \left(1-\frac1{f_0x}-\frac1{f_1f_0x}-\frac1{f_2f_1f_0x}-\dots\right),
$$
therefore it is basically stating that
$$
\sqrt{1-\frac1{x^2}} = 1-\frac1{f_0x}-\frac1{f_1f_0x}-\frac1{f_2f_1f_0x}-\dots
$$

This is just an asymptotic expansion of the square root, and is completely decoupled from the original Pell equation.